# Android -- Help with XML of a "complex" row in a ListView

Tags: xml, android, listview

I have a relatively complex layout that I'd like to be the "row" of a ListView in Android and I'm having trouble getting the right-most element to show up on each row.

Here's what the row *should* look like:

There's an icon (50dip x 50dip) on the left and an icon (9 x 13) on the right.  The icons should be left and right justified, respectively with variable text in the middle.

Problem is that my right-most icon (9 x 13) is pushed off of the visible area using my current XML layout and my attempted fixes have all failed.

Suggestions??

![alt text][1]

[1]: [image: Hosted by imgur.com]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip">
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:minHeight="55dip"
            android:padding="5dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip" android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />
            <TextView android:ellipsize="end" android:textColor="#454545"
                android:id="@+id/ttt" android:textSize="18sp" android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="13dip" android:minWidth="9dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/disclosure" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a `RelativeLayout` with `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight` attributes? I think it would be simpler and use lesser number of LayoutManagers. Something like the following: Note that this assumes the height of the row as 50dip and that of both the images as 50x50 dip.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:text="some text"/>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One thing to add to TextView is android:layout_margin="50dp", in other case the long text will overlap with images.

Comment: Another general layout tip: you can the `android:leftDrawable` property (or `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` method) of a `TextView` to avoid even needing the `ImageView` on the left.